# Google Cloud Vision API response structure

Tags: google-cloud-vision

Getting this response when invoking vision.documentTextDetection()

```
[{ 
    faceAnnotations: [],
    landmarkAnnotations: [],
    logoAnnotations: [],
    labelAnnotations: [],
    textAnnotations: [],
    localizedObjectAnnotations: [],
    safeSearchAnnotation: null,
    imagePropertiesAnnotation: null,
    error: null,
    cropHintsAnnotation: null,
    fullTextAnnotation: null,
    webDetection: null,
    context: null 
}]
```

What's the point in some properties as empty arrays and some as null?
I'm trying to make conditional rendering and got stuck on truthy values when IRL they aren't.

Comment: can you please elaborate question more vividly?

Comment: How do make conditional rendering? Since this is a json, you can easily neglect null values if you don't want those properties.

Comment: @kvk30 Thanks! I was trying to call various functions depending on if-else. Since empty arrays are true, I think there is some certain logic behind that.

Comment: Hi, i suggest you make conditional rendering by considering the length of arrays. If it is a empty array then the length of it will be 0, so you can just ignore it.

Comment: @NimeshaKalinga Yep, that could be done, thank you! I was interested in the internal logic of such a structure. Why does Vision API answer me with a truthy value when actually it's false?

Comment: Empty arrays are truthy.  That's just the way JavaScript works.  If you want to know if an array is empty, then check its length, don't evaluate it as a boolean.

Comment: I think, they've defined a default API structure to send to every request it receives. That is because API is not only answering for text detection, but other things like image detection, smile detection etc.
https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/rest/v1/images/annotate
Above link shows there default response structure.

Comment: @DougStevenson Thank for a reply! I was just confused that calling documentTextDetection() `faceAnnotations` is truthy while others of the same level are not. E.g. `safeSearchAnnotations` is a boolean indeed. What's the logic behind it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't speak for the creators of the API, but it makes sense in terms of you writing less code to get more work done.

If the array fields in question are always arrays and nothing else, then you simply make the assumption in your code that they are arrays.  This means that if you want to know if something was returned in that array *safely*, then all you have to do is check the length of the array, or just iterate it.

On the other hand, if the array fields in question are *sometimes* arrays, maybe null, then you have to write code to first check if the array field is null, then write code to check the array.

Which would you rather do?  1) Assume the field is an array and deal with it.  Or 2) Check to see if it's actually an array, then deal with it as such?  Seems to me that it's more convenient to just assume array, and write less code.

Comment: It all makes sense now from this perspective. Also maybe you know if it's possible to combine 2 requests in Node instead of separately calling e.g. vision.faceAnnotations() and vision.documentTextDetection() on the same image?

Comment: That sounds like a different question to ask on SO.